# ModalPopupExtender Error

Tags: c#, ajax, visual-studio-2008, modalpopupextender

i want to popup ModalPopupExtender in button click, but when i run my code and click on the button then ModalPopupExtender is not popup even i used all the required AjaxControlToolkit references for this

### my code is following :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#CC3300">
    hello...
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="click here" />

    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Button1">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
</div>
</form>
```

i am using the visual studio 2008 Pro., .Net Framework 3.5 and for Ajax i used AjaxControlToolkit.dll(3.5.60919.0)

sir, plz give me solution for this..

Answer (score 3):

it can be your tags, try `ajaxToolkit` instead of `asp` tag

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Button1">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: i m tried it but it show the following error                     Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender'.

Comment: that means you configured your toolkit controls tag as `asp:`, ajaxcontroltoolkit comes with default tag `ajaxToolkit:`. İs this your first try with an ajaxcontroltoolkit control or did you use any control before?

Comment: yes i did, it is not my first time with ajaxcontroltoolkit, sir when i replace the AjaxControlToolkit.dll(3.5.60919.0) with the AjaxControlToolkit.dll(1.0.10123.0) in bin folder and i run my code then it work correctly but with the AjaxControlToolkit.dll(3.5.60919.0) it does not work. and when i drag the AjaxControl from toolbar to my form then there is bin folder for ajax is created with the AjaxControlToolkit.dll(3.5.60919.0)

Comment: i assume you upgraded from version 1.0 to version 3.5 of AjaxControlToolkit.dll, you probably need to remove the Ajax Control Toolkit folder from your toolbox and update it as well. if it still doesnt work, best solution would be uninstalling AjaxControlToolkit and reinstalling the new version

Comment: ok sir thank, sir i have on another doubt plz clear it. when i create a new website in visual studio 2008 Pro. then here in New Web Site Dialog box it is tell us that it is a .Net Framework 3.5 but when i print that code - "Response.Write(System.Environment.Version.ToString());" then it is print "2.0.50727.3053" why it so, while at the time when i was create a new website then in New Web Site Dialog box it is tell us that it is a .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: i think the response is from the server, so displayed version is not your website version you used but the version installed on the server

Answer (score 0):

I believe your workaround lies here:

[unknown server tag modalpopupextender](http://forums.asp.net/post/1871283.aspx)

The error is related to the use of a master page in your site and was reportedly going to be fixed in a Visual Studio service pack (as of 2007, but not yet as of VS 2010 SP1).  There is a simple workaround though that works for some folks (and did for me):

Open the master page first, then open the page with your `ModalPopupExtender` in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Need to include the below line in your aspx page at the top .
Just change the version according to your's.**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1005, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" %>
```